# List attachments not appearing on query.iqy in Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have exported a list to excel so that I can view all new submissions in excel without having to view them in Sharepoint but attachments are not in the list even though they are on the original SP list I exported? Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, when I export the list to excel, there is no attachment in excel file.

It is by design.

We cannot export to excel with attachment column.

There is a workaround.

We can open the list in the Access and then export the list from Access to excel. Then in the excel, there is the attachment column.

[image]

There is a similar post:

[Export list to list with Attachment column](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/86b1a549-41c7-4665-b8bd-c86694e0692d/export-list-to-list-with-attachment-column?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open MS-Excel.
2. Connect to your SharePoint site using path shown below.
   [image]
3. Connect to your site using credentials.
4. Select your list from the navigator.
   [image]

[image]

5. Work on transforming your data as required using load or transform data buttons.